# Converting CSV data for access inside classes

Tags: javascript, typescript, csv

I am trying to develop TypeScript classes to access data in a csv file. The original spreadsheet looks like this:

[image]

I took that and converted it into a CSV file and quickly parsed it like so:

```
import fs from "fs";

const data = fs.readFileSync("Data-Table 1.csv", {
  encoding: "utf-8",
});

console.log(data);
```

But if course it looks like this:

[start:run] 1848,,,432-444 W. Ocean Blvd,4,1312-03,-888,,432-444 W. Ocean Blvd,"Recommendation to certify a Mitigated Negative Declaration (MND 01-14) in accordance with CEQA Guidelines and approve a Site Plan Review, Local Coastal Development Permit, and Vesting Tentative Tract Map for the construction of an eight-story residential apartment complex consisting of 95 residential units and 153 parking spaces within a three-level parking garage at 442 W. Ocean Boulevard in Subarea 4 of the Downtown Shoreline Planned Development District PD-6. The Vesting Tentative Tract Map is for the merger of two lots into one ground space lot and two airspace lots at 432-444 W. Ocean Boulevard. (District 2) (Application No. 1312-03)",-888,2,-999,-999,-999,LUD 7 - Mixed Use,PD-6,2,"surface parking lot; office building, office tower",-999,-999,-999,0,0,0,23522,-888,95,0,-999,  1 ,2,153,19,80,-999,0,1,43,21,25,6,0,0,0,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,0,-888,-888,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,1,0,-999,-999,12/5/2013,5/21/2015,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,1,12/5/2013,5/21/2015,1,12/5/2013,5/21/2015,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,1,-999,-999,,,-999,-888,12/5/2013,5/21/2015,532d,-999,-999,4,2,-999,-888,0,-999,-999,-999,-999,0,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,-999,33.767216946954,-118.197018766954,,,,,,,,,

There is a lot of `-999` throughout the spreadsheet that don't do anything, it's useless.

But what I would like to do is develop this into a data structure that I can access via TypeScript classes.

So my thinking is that the data needs to ideally look something like this:

```
const data = [
  {Address: '123 Main Street', Development_Plan: 'Downtown' },
  {Address: '21 Peaceful Way', Development_Plan: 'Residential' },
];
```

How should I convert my CSV data into the above format?

I am seeking example code. I have tried other ways such as calling split on this blob of strings and turned them into an array of strings and then I mapped over each individual string, split on the comma and eventually ended up with a two-dimensional string.

I obviously went way of course to what I am looking for above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but it should work

```
class Data {
    address: string;
    developmentPlan: string;

    static DELIMITER = ",";

    constructor(rawRow: string) {
        const data= rawRow.split(Data.DELIMITER);

        this.address = data[8];
        this.developmentPlan = data[9]; // change the index based on the cols position
    }
}

const ROW_DELIMITER = "\r\n";

const rawData = fs.readFileSync("Data-Table 1.csv", {
    encoding: "utf-8",
});

const data: Data[] = [];

for (const rawRow of rawData.split(ROW_DELIMITER)) {
    data.push(new Data(rawRow));
}

console.log(data);
```

Comment: is there anyway this can be written where I do not have to pass in `rawRow: string` to the constructor? Where I don't have to pass anything at all into the constructor?